# How do I change the style property of my array-bars in componentDidMount()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I made a sorting algorithm visualiser which displays vertical bars of different heights and sort them. I have used a button here called "Generate new Array" which will call a function to generate new array everytime and I have also used this function in componentDidMount() function. How do I change the style property whenever I click that button? 
I tried taking `document.getElementByClassName('array-bars')` into an array and change its style property using loop but its not happeneing. I am adding the necessary code below.

```
{ //array is const storing array of numbers which is also only state of this program.
  array.map((value, idx) => (
    <div
      className="array-bar"
      key={idx}
      style={{ height: value, backgroundColor: 'turquoise' }}></div>))
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.resetArray();
}

// this is called when I click generate new array    
resetArray(){
  const array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    array.push(randomIntFromInterval(15, 650));
  }
  const arrayBars = document.getElementByClassName('array-bar');
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayBars.length; i++)
    arrayBars[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green'; //this is failing

  this.setState({ array });
}
```

Edited:
This is function where I am changing style property using the method written in above code. Its working here.
Also, Can you tell how can I change the color in this mergeSort() in last?
I tried using `this.setState()` at last but that's changing the color in the beginning only.

```
 mergeSort(){
         for(let i=0;i<animations.length;i++){
             const arrayBars= document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
             const colorChange=i%3!==2;
             if(colorChange){
                 const [barOne,barTwo] =animations[i];
                 const barOneStyle=arrayBars[barOne].style;
                 const barTwoStyle=arrayBars[barTwo].style;
                 const color=i%3===0?'red':'turquoise';
                 setTimeout(()=>{
                    barOneStyle.backgroundColor=color;
                    barTwoStyle.backgroudColor=color;
                 },i*2);
             }
             else{
                 setTimeout(()=>{
                    const[barOne,newHeight]=animations[i];
                    const barOneStyle=arrayBars[barOne].style;
                    barOneStyle.height=newHeight+'px';
                 },i*2)
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: How about, on click, you set a value in state and that will conditionally add a class to those elements in `render` function. So in your click, you have to set this value as true and your job is done

Answer (score 0):

In React, you should rely on **state** changes to "make things happen". As suggested by other in the question comments, set an initial state containing the initial background color and update the value as needed. 
UPDATE: If you want changes to happen after button click, just set its `onclick` attribute to point to a function that does what you want. Here I added a button and pointed its `onclick` attribute to `resetArrays`.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      barBg: 'turquoise'
    }
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
     <button onClick={this.resetArray.bind(this)}>Generate new array</button>
     { //array is const storing array of numbers which is also only state of this program.
      array.map((value, idx) => (
        <div
         className="array-bar"
         key={idx}
         style={{ height: value, backgroundColor: this.state.barBg }}></div>))
      }
     </div>
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.resetArray();
  }

  // this is called when I click generate new array    
  resetArray(){
    const array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
      array.push(randomIntFromInterval(15, 650));
    }

    this.setState({ array, barBg: 'green' });
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply rewriting code is not a good answer - please explain what you've done

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Answer got accidentally submitted while writing.

Comment: But can you explain why my method is not giving results? I have used this same procedure in some other method and its working there.

Comment: Also, what you suggested is not working. Its only working for the first time when component mount.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I have edited the code, you can see.

Comment: @konoufo No. It didn't work. I did exactly the same.

Comment: @AmanDhaka I feel it's not clear what you want to achieve. Take a look at this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-violet-kwsj8?file=/src/App.js:940-942) and tell me what is different from your goal

Comment: @konoufo `changeColor(){
    this.setState({barBg: "green" });
  }` 
Just change the onClick method of "Generate new Array" button . And you will see that background color doesn't change to green color when we click that button.
My goal is that When I click the button the background color changes . If its blue at start then it should  change to green when I click certain button. I hope you get me. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-https-38nmm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @AmanDhaka Your code is incorrect; `this.props.changeColor` does not exist you should be using `this.changeColor`. Plus I apparently mispelled the `onClick`property. Now it works [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-tereshkova-xzi0q?file=/src/App.js)